# Understand this piece of Python code with decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

So I am trying to decipher some code from the [here](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/align/detect_face.py). Below I have copy and pasted the relevant code that I don't really understand.

```
def layer(op):
    '''Decorator for composable network layers.'''

    def layer_decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Automatically set a name if not provided.
        name = kwargs.setdefault('name', self.get_unique_name(op.__name__))
        # Figure out the layer inputs.
        if len(self.terminals) == 0:
            raise RuntimeError('No input variables found for layer %s.' % name)
        elif len(self.terminals) == 1:
            layer_input = self.terminals[0]
        else:
            layer_input = list(self.terminals)
        # Perform the operation and get the output.
        layer_output = op(self, layer_input, *args, **kwargs)
        # Add to layer LUT.
        self.layers[name] = layer_output
        # This output is now the input for the next layer.
        self.feed(layer_output)
        # Return self for chained calls.
        return self

    return layer_decorated

class Network(object):

    def __init__(self, inputs, trainable=True):
        # The input nodes for this network
        self.inputs = inputs
        print(self.inputs)
        # The current list of terminal nodes
        self.terminals = []
        # Mapping from layer names to layers
        self.layers = dict(inputs)
        print(self.layers)
        # If true, the resulting variables are set as trainable
        self.trainable = trainable

    …

    def feed(self, *args):
        '''Set the input(s) for the next operation by replacing the terminal nodes.
        The arguments can be either layer names or the actual layers.
        '''
        assert len(args) != 0
        self.terminals = []
        for fed_layer in args:
            if isinstance(fed_layer, string_types):
                try:
                    fed_layer = self.layers[fed_layer]
                except KeyError:
                    raise KeyError('Unknown layer name fed: %s' % fed_layer)
            self.terminals.append(fed_layer)
        return self

 ....

 # equivalent to max_pool = layer(max_pool)
    @layer
    def max_pool(self, inp, k_h, k_w, s_h, s_w, name, padding='SAME'):
        self.validate_padding(padding)
        return tf.nn.max_pool(inp,
                              ksize=[1, k_h, k_w, 1],
                              strides=[1, s_h, s_w, 1],
                              padding=padding,
                              name=name)
```

I understand the above code, although I've having a bit of trouble trying to understand the code below:

```
class PNet(Network):
    def setup(self):
        (self.feed('data') 
             .conv(3, 3, 10, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv1')
             .prelu(name='PReLU1')
             .max_pool(2, 2, 2, 2, name='pool1')
             .conv(3, 3, 16, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv2')
             .prelu(name='PReLU2')
             .conv(3, 3, 32, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv3')
             .prelu(name='PReLU3')
             .conv(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, relu=False, name='conv4-1')
             .softmax(3,name='prob1'))

        (self.feed('PReLU3') #pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
             .conv(1, 1, 4, 1, 1, relu=False, name='conv4-2'))
```

In particular, I'm confused in the this part of the code works:

```
self.feed('data') 
             .conv(3, 3, 10, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv1')
             .prelu(name='PReLU1')
             .max_pool(2, 2, 2, 2, name='pool1')
             .conv(3, 3, 16, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv2')
             .prelu(name='PReLU2')
             .conv(3, 3, 32, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv3')
             .prelu(name='PReLU3')
             .conv(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, relu=False, name='conv4-1')
             .softmax(3,name='prob1'))
```

It can also be written as:
`self.feed('data').conv(3, 3, 10, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv1').prelu(name='PReLU1')...`

And this is the what I don't understand, `feed` itself is a method of the `Network` class, but how am I able to access `feed`'s methods etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with decorators. There is a `return self` in `feed()`, same for the other methods presumably. `self` is just another reference to the current instance, so the next method in the chain is called on `self` again, so you can call another method, etc. The decorator, too, returns `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with decorators.

The `feed` method - as well as, presumably, the `conv` and `prelu` methods - return `self`. This means you can continue to call methods on the result of calling that method.

This is known as "method chaining"; it's more common in languages like Ruby, but you can do it in Python too.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple really.

So when you are starting this chain you have object `self` on which you call it's method `feed()` method executes and if you look into source code it returns `self`. But it's the modified self. So at this point `feed()` is 'consumed' and you are left with something like `(modified)self.prelu()....`. And this repeats with another method. And it repeats until there are no calls left.